# Blazor WASM scroll event not firing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Im on the latest version of `Blazor WASM` and trying to animate my navbar on scroll, but the `onscroll` event is not firing at all.

I've tried the `@onscroll` event from `Blazor` as well as the native `onscroll` event in different places of my app, but neither work. I've also tried `JSInterop` to subscribe to `window.onscroll` but its also not working. The only thing I got to work is the `@onwheel` event from `Blazor`, but this does not work with other types of scrolling.

Is this simply not supported in `Blazor` at the moment or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-5.0#dont-trigger-events-too-rapidly), `@onscroll` event is not recommended to handle scroll. Because it may harm UI responsiveness or consume excessive CPU time. So you may prefer to use JS interop to register a callback that fires less frequently.

For example, add an ElementReference in div. This code in Index.razor.

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@implements IDisposable

<div @ref="scrollElement" style="border:1px dashed red;height:100px;width:200px;overflow:auto">
In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
<br><br>
'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
</div>

@code {
  ElementReference scrollElement;

  DotNetObjectReference<Index> selfReference;

  protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
  {
    if (firstRender)
    {
        selfReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
        var minInterval = 500; // Only notify every 500 ms
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("onDivScroll",
            scrollElement, minInterval);
    }
  }

  public void Dispose() => selfReference?.Dispose();
}
```

Create a javascript file.

```
function onDivScroll(elem, interval) {
  elem.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
      console.log(e)
  }, interval);
}
```

Then reference it in _Index.html.

```
<script src="./filename.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: Modified the js part to listen on the document itself, but this answer worken for me, thanks!

Comment: Of course I don't want to have this red window on my gui.
But when I do width + height: auto or 100% or without or display: table-cell; 
than I don't get the scroll event. How can it fit the parent and send the scroll event?